# Java wildcard error

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have a BaseDao interface to persist data to mysql using hibernate

```
public interface BaseDao<T extends Serializable> {
    public void saveAll(Collection<T> objects) throws PersistenceException;
}
```

i have an entity classes hirechy that their base class is BaseActivity (all extends serializable)
one of them:

```
public class Activity1 extends BaseACtivity{...}
```

in some class i'm declaring ActivityDao:

```
 protected abstract ActivityDao<Activity1> createActivityDao1();
```

and a method:

```
 private void  persistData(ActivityDao<? extends BaseActivity> activityDao, Collection<? extends BaseActivity> data){
    EntityTransaction transaction = activityDao.getEntityManager().getTransaction();

    try {
        transaction.begin();

        activityDao.saveAll(data);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
```

at activityDao.saveAll(data) i'm getting a compile time exception:

```
 Error:(62, 24) java: method saveAll in interface com.matomy.persistence.dao.BaseDao<T>
 cannot be applied to given types;
 required: java.util.Collection<capture#1 of ? extends
 com.matomy.persistence.entity.activities.BaseActivity>
 found: java.util.Collection<capture#2 of ? extends   com.matomy.persistence.entity.activities.BaseActivity>
 reason: actual argument java.util.Collection<capture#2 of ? extends     com.matomy.persistence.entity.activities.BaseActivity>
 cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<capture#1 of ? extends     com.matomy.persistence.entity.activities.BaseActivity> 
 by method invocation conversion
```

BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity implements Serializable, Comparable<BaseActivity> {
```

Help please
Thanks!

Roy

UPDATE:

```
private <T extends BaseActivity> void  persistData(ActivityDao<T> activityDao, Collection<T> col){
    EntityTransaction transaction = activityDao.getEntityManager().getTransaction();

    try {
        transaction.begin();

        activityDao.saveAll(col);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
```

Comment: Is BaseActivity Serializable?

Comment: yes: public abstract class BaseActivity implements Serializable, Comparable<BaseActivity> {

Comment: Well, that would be tedious. And this is the same issue. You've to find some way to make that class generic. Or you would need some dirty workaround to make that work.

Comment: thanks! removed because it's really the same issue. i've solved it using Wrapper class for both the collection and the activityDao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of two bounded wildcards with the same bound doesn't mean they are the same type. In this case, the actual type argument for `ActivityDao<? extends BaseActivity>` might not be same as the one coming with `Collection<? extends BaseActivity>`. So, the `saveAll()` method wouldn't work.

To elaborate further, the compiler replaces each wildcard occurrence with a unique placeholder which is nothing but *capture of that wildcard*. That means, `Collection<?>` becomes `Collection<CAP#1 of ?>`, similarly `Collection<? extends T>` becomes `Collection<CAP#1 of ? extends T>`. If a `Collection<?>` is again encountered, it will be replaced with `Collection<CAP#2 of ?>`.

So, your method declaration is somewhat similar to:

```
private void  persistData(ActivityDao<CAP#1-of-? extends BaseActivity> activityDao, Collection<CAP#2-of-? extends BaseActivity> data){
    EntityTransaction transaction = activityDao.getEntityManager().getTransaction();

    try {
        transaction.begin();

        activityDao.saveAll(data);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
    }
}
```

where `CAP#1` and `CAP#2` are different type parameters for compiler. Of course, the signature of `saveAll` for that method becomes like this:

```
public void saveAll(Collection<CAP#1-of-? extends BaseActivity> objects) throws PersistenceException;
```

And since *`Collection<T1>` is not the same as `Collection<T2>`* for two different type arguments, so that method invocation fails.

You can resolve this issue by using generic method instead:

```
private <T extends BaseActivity> void persistData(ActivityDao<T> activityDao, Collection<T> data){
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! it is the case. before posting the question i have tried to implement the method as a template method but then the problem is that i have 2 fields with wildcards that when passing them to the method results at the same error. i'm updating the code